# Extract frames according to audio signal in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I need to extract frames from a video according to the audio stream, which is a silent track with a beep (like a square wave, 10KHz I think but I'm not sure) on the frames to be extracted. What would be the best way to proceed? Is there a filter that can tell me what is the sound corresponding to each frame? Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: In your place I would write a custom program, using a library (via ffmpeg or directly) to read the combined stream (whatever kind of stream it is). I don't think you can do such specific tasks efficiently from the command line.

Comment: Give me a few days to post a method. I implemented something similar a couple of years ago. Share full readout of `ffmpeg -i input`.  Sharing such a file would be ideal.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't have the file yet, it's an idea that I have but still need some time to develop correctly. I am thinking on methods for using the audio stream as a trigger so to say, so if anything comes to mind it would be greatly appreciated, I am reading ffmpeg documentation in case I stumble with some hints. The ideal would be a filter but I don't think that such a thing exists and I think writing one myself is a bit out of my league.